# Trying to understand coroutines - not getting expected output

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Here is my code where I am trying to use a coroutine:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update(){
        StartCoroutine (Test());
        print ("in update");
    }

    IEnumerator Test()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
            print(i);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I just wanted to check the difference between how normal functions behave in update versus using coroutines. I have read that coroutines preserve the values of their local variables. But I am getting weird output.

[See the image for output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA62H.png)

Comment: Let me know if my answer satisfactorily solved your problem - also consider reading the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) on `StartCoroutine()`, since they give some well-explained example usages there.

Comment: Hi Shri .. you need to tick Serlite's generous answer.  The "documentation" page for Coroutines is not bad http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/unity3d/3415/coroutines#t=201702071124331182704

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're starting a new coroutine every `Update()` call. As a result, more and more instances of `Test()` are going to be run in parallel, and they'll all be at different points in the iteration - that's why your log is filling up with different numbers every frame (0, 0 1, 0 1 2, 0 1 2 3, etc.)

What you should be doing is starting the coroutine from your `Start()` method instead of your `Update()` method, so it only gets started once:

```
void Start(){
    StartCoroutine (Test());
}

void Update(){
    print ("in update");
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much...you explained it very well @Serlite